# I have to hit command keys twice (E.G. alt-tab to switch windows)

Tags: unity, 18.04, shortcut-keys, ubuntu-mate

Context:

It was a while ago but I think I originally:

- Installed a previous release of Ubuntu, accidentally using the pure version
- Installed the MATE desktop packages on top of that
- Did a distribution upgrade to 18.04

After that I've had to hit command keys twice, like <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> if I want to switch windows or <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> if I want to open the run-program dialogue.

I also had to enter my password twice when unlocking, but I've since fixed that by following the instructions on a different question and uninstalling the gnome-screensaver package.

I probably have two desktops running, or some similar program in that domain. Can anyone make a guess as to which programs that might be?